# How do I connect to my SSH VPS in google cloud?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, debian, vps

So im really new with these VPS stuff, Always wanted to host my discord bots in them, Then I see Google cloud with a $300 credit so I said why not, After I signed up and created an EC2 instance Thing is though, I've never used a VPS on SSH, I've tried tutorials on youtube but none works. My questions is, How do I connect to my SSH VPS through "FileZilla" or "PuTTy"? I've tried PuTTyGen like in youtube vids, But they don't bring me to my "captionedcan" account. So I can't really import anything to my "captionedcan"s folders.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I can see that you are familiar with AWS, but I want to let you know that there are some differences on the name of the services, for example Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) has its equivalent in Google Cloud Platform, its name is [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute) you could check the following [document](https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws#service_comparisons) that provides a side-by-side comparison of the various services available on AWS and Google Cloud.

On the other hand, a simple way to connect to Linux instance (Your VPS) is through the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/?_ga=2.229472158.305402083.1598273128-638966553.1591892739) and you can follow the next steps:

1. In the Cloud Console, go to the [**VM instances**](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances?_ga=2.258947080.305402083.1598273128-638966553.1591892739) page.
2. In the list of virtual machine instances, click **SSH** in the row of the instance that you want to connect to.

[image]

I hope you find this information useful.

Comment: I've found a video with information that may help you, it explains further the ssh login:  [Troubleshooting OS Login SSH access](https://youtu.be/sTiswpYxZgU?t=63)